# Frigidaire clothes washer drum does not turn

Tags: appliances, washing-machine

My Frigidaire front loading washing machine has stopped turning. I have let it run through a short cycle, and the timer does run through the entire cycle. The drum fills up, and the pump operates to drain the tub, but when it is time for the drum to turn, nothing happens, not even any sounds. I did see the drum turn backwards slightly once, but that is all.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Additional information, took the top and back off. Watched it go through a cycle. Belt is fine. The motor does move periodically, but not much. Just enough to make the drum tun a bit. The drum turns easily. I think one of the controller boards inside has failed. Which one should I replace first.

Comment: Broken or glazed (slipping) belt? Or maybe there's a belt tensioner that is broken or maladjusted?

Comment: Does it make any sounds?  It is common that the drive screws become loose but this is usually pretty noisy.

Comment: Turned out to be a failed motor controller. 15 minute repair including watching shorty wash cycle long enough to see it go from start to spin.